# Servlet for only forwarded requests

Tags: servlets

I would like to pass some requests from my first servlet (A) to the second one (B) using RequestDispatcher. And the question is: how can I check if request in B servlet comes from A forwarding and handle only these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A**, you can [set an attribute in the request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), which you can then read in **B**.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of Servlet B is to only handle requests coming from Servlet A, then you would be better off writing a simple Java class that does what you need, and then returns details that you can use in Servlet A to decide what to do next.

It's possible to use another Servlet for the additional functionality, but is not clean design.

Comment: Both servlets have special functions and I can't resign from any of them.

Comment: Who wrote both Servlets? If the B shouldn't be called/used from anywhere else other than A, then why can't you refactor B to be a simple class?

Comment: First one is asynchronous spring servlet, the second one - com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.